# Date Boost Fails After Solr Upgrade to 7.2

Tags: solr

Date boost fails after upgrade to solr 7.2.1 from 4.9.0

Original working 4.9.0 url:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/facet?fq=-url:http*&fq=-facet_encatname:reference\-documents*&fq=+id:doc*&q{!boost+b=$dateboost+v=$qq}&dateboost=recip(ms(NOW/DAY,soldate),3.16e-11,1,1)&qq=*:*
```

With that url in 4.9.0, I get [numFound] => 647, in 7.2.1 I get [numFound] => 0. There is no score with 7.2.1 as there are no docs found.

Initially, I tried only making the required changes for the upgrade, which were actually few and still allowed my TrieDateField. As the query failed, I tried changing my date field (soldate) to a DatePointField, then DateRangeField, with no success. The change logs don't seem to offer any hint.

I made no changes to the requestHandler other than dropping boosts which are no longer supported. I still have defType edismax.

My debug=query for 4.9.0 starts:

```
    [debug] => Array
    (
        [rawquerystring] => {!boost b=$dateboost v=$qq}
        [querystring] => {!boost b=$dateboost v=$qq}
        [parsedquery] => BoostedQuery(boost(*:*,1.0/(3.16E-11*float(ms(const(1518652800000),date(soldate)))+1.0)))
        [parsedquery_toString] => boost(*:*,1.0/(3.16E-11*float(ms(const(1518652800000),date(soldate)))+1.0))
        [QParser] => LuceneQParser
        [boost_str] => recip(ms(NOW/DAY,soldate),3.16e-11,1,1)
        [boost_parsed] => org.apache.lucene.queries.function.valuesource.ReciprocalFloatFunction:1.0/(3.16E-11*float(ms(const(1518652800000),date(soldate)))+1.0)
        [filter_queries] => Array
         ...
```

With 7.2.1, I get:

```
    [debug] => Array
    (
        [rawquerystring] => {!boost b=$dateboost v=$qq}
        [querystring] => {!boost b=$dateboost v=$qq}
        [parsedquery] => +DisjunctionMaxQuery((((summary:boost summary:b summary:dateboost summary:v summary:qq)~4)^10.0 | ((provname:boost provname:b provname:dateboost provname:v provname:qq)~4) | ((lstitle:boost lstitle:b lstitle:dateboost lstitle:v lstitle:qq)~4)^10.0 | ((rtdcontent:boost rtdcontent:b rtdcontent:dateboost rtdcontent:v rtdcontent:qq)~4) | ((city:boost city:b city:dateboost city:v city:qq)~4)^2.0 | ((ltxt:boost ltxt:b ltxt:dateboost ltxt:v ltxt:qq)~4)^3.0 | ((Synonym(contact:bo contact:bos contact:bost contact:bot contact:bust contact:vost) Synonym(contact:f contact:p) Synonym(contact:dYtYbost contact:dYtibost contact:datYbost contact:datibo contact:datibos contact:datibost contact:datibot contact:datibust contact:dativost contact:dotYbost contact:dotibo contact:dotibos contact:dotibost contact:dotibot contact:dotibust contact:dotivost) Synonym(contact:f contact:p) contact:k)~4)^5.0 | ((cname:boost cname:b cname:dateboost cname:v cname:qq)~4) | ((geo_name:boost geo_name:b geo_name:dateboost geo_name:v geo_name:qq)~4)))
        [parsedquery_toString] => +(((summary:boost summary:b summary:dateboost summary:v summary:qq)~4)^10.0 | ((provname:boost provname:b provname:dateboost provname:v provname:qq)~4) | ((lstitle:boost lstitle:b lstitle:dateboost lstitle:v lstitle:qq)~4)^10.0 | ((rtdcontent:boost rtdcontent:b rtdcontent:dateboost rtdcontent:v rtdcontent:qq)~4) | ((city:boost city:b city:dateboost city:v city:qq)~4)^2.0 | ((ltxt:boost ltxt:b ltxt:dateboost ltxt:v ltxt:qq)~4)^3.0 | ((Synonym(contact:bo contact:bos contact:bost contact:bot contact:bust contact:vost) Synonym(contact:f contact:p) Synonym(contact:dYtYbost contact:dYtibost contact:datYbost contact:datibo contact:datibos contact:datibost contact:datibot contact:datibust contact:dativost contact:dotYbost contact:dotibo contact:dotibos contact:dotibost contact:dotibot contact:dotibust contact:dotivost) Synonym(contact:f contact:p) contact:k)~4)^5.0 | ((cname:boost cname:b cname:dateboost cname:v cname:qq)~4) | ((geo_name:boost geo_name:b geo_name:dateboost geo_name:v geo_name:qq)~4))
        [facet-debug] => Array
        ...
        [QParser] => ExtendedDismaxQParser
        ...
```

Obviously, solr has changed a lot, but from what I have read eDismax supports everything the LuceneQParser does, syntax wise. I tried adding !lucene, but it still comes back [QParser] => ExtendedDismaxQParser

I have spent days searching and looking through the output from debug for all of my tests. While I have been using Solr for years, this upgrade has me cold.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Jeff

Comment: Have you compared the scores from `debugQuery=true` between the two versions and seen where they differ?